Why was the Secret Service translated into 特勤局?
The Secret Service in the US provides coverage and protection to VIPs as in the recent case of the shooting at Donald Trump.
But most of the Chinese language media used the words 特勤局 for this service provider.
I don't understand why they did so because there is no 特勤局 in China (警卫局 in the mainland and 政治组 in Hong Kong serve the similar purpose respectively), what's more, both of the words Secret and Service have nothing to do with the Chinese characters 特 and 勤.
Could anyone explain?

There's several things wrong in the question, e.g. (1) 特勤 is a word meaning Special Duties or Special Services so it's not true that "the words Secret and Service have nothing to do with the Chinese characters 特 and 勤"; (2) China has a 公安部特勤局. A brief fact-check tells you that the US Secret Service is made up of mainly Special Agents (Agents performing Special Duties), so the Chinese name obviously means "Special Duties Agency".

Following on from @dRoooze comment, the US Secret Service does not only provide personal protective services for VIPs, but also many other duties besides. The Secret Service was initially established on July 5, 1865, in Washington, D.C., to suppress counterfeit currency. After the assassination of President William McKinley in 1901, Congress informally requested that the Secret Service also provide presidential protection.

@dROOOze Even the function and service of the institutions of the two countries are the same as you said, I do not see any one has translated the NYPD as 纽约市公安局

The "USS Secret Service" is a federal law enforcement agency(局) under the Dept of Homeland Security(国土安全部). It is mandated by Congress with two distinct and critical national security missions - "protecting" the nation's leaders and "safeguarding" the financial and critical infrastructure of the United States."
Note that neither of the missions has anything to do with "secret" but as a "special(特別) service(勤務)" not included in the scope of normal law enforcement.

So you mean they have misnamed the institute and the translation helps correct it?

In this case, the translator chose to translate an agency's name based on its function rather than word-by-word translation, which might make it difficult for the local people to get the idea, or get the wrong idea. Compared to "密秘勤務局", the translation is more "貼切" to the agency's primary missions.

How about 东厂or 锦衣卫?

I don't know the relevance of the question about these two ancient agencies. if you want to know more, start a new thread.

I mean that some of you believe that 特勤局 can be used for the Secret Service because they have the same function so it is also right to use 东厂 or 锦衣卫 for the same purpose.

To my concern, your question was answered. For anything not included in the original, you can modify it to include the additional question(s), or open a new thread.

I did not say anything to make you unhappy, did I ? Your answer, which is unnecessily, could have been more friendly.  The 10 points you earned from this question was given by me if you could check it out.

Why not start a new thread and ask "What is the English equivalent of 东厂 or 锦衣卫?" I think you may receive many interesting answers.

Found this:
秘密服务的英文翻译为"Secret Service"，‌
The English translation of 秘密服务 is Secret Service,
而"特勤局"的翻译可能源于特勤局的原始职能和名称的演变。‌
but the translation of (Secret Service) as "特勤局" may be the result of the Secret Service's original function and the development of its name.
特勤局的名称最初源于其打击造假币的使命，‌
The name Secret Service first originated in its mission of combating counterfeit money.
这个名称反映了其成立初期的职能和特点。‌
This name reflected its initial role and characteristic (when) it was established.
英语中，‌"Secret Service"的字面意思是“秘密服务”，‌
In English, the literal meaning of "Secret Service" is “秘密服务”,
强调的是其秘密行动和特工的隐蔽性。‌
to emphasise its secret activity and nature.
然而，‌随着时间的发展和职能的扩展，‌
However, as time passed its roles were extended,
"Secret Service"逐渐被翻译为"特勤局"，‌
the translation of "Secret Service" gradually changed to become "特勤局, Special Diligence Office"
这里的"特勤"可能意指特殊勤务或者特种任务，‌
this "Special Diligence" may indicate its special duties and / or special missions,
强调了特勤局执行的任务具有特殊性、‌紧急性和重要性。‌
emphasising 特勤局 carries out special missions which have a special urgent nature or importance,
这种翻译可能也反映了中文中对类似机构的一种习惯性称呼，‌
Possibly, this translation reflects the Chinese habit of naming similar kinds of agencies,
即使用“特勤”来指代那些执行特殊任务的机构或部门。‌
namely "Special Diligence" to name those departments and agencies which carry out special missions.
在美国，‌
In America,
特勤局主要负责保护前任和现任美国总统、‌
Special Diligence Office is mainly responsible for protecting former presidents and the current president,
保护国家领导人、‌以及进行反假币、‌反恐怖主义等任务。‌
protecting the nations leaders, as well as combating counterfeiters, (and) counter-terrorism.
这些职能体现了特勤局作为国家安全重要组成部分的角色，‌
The embodiment of these roles by the Special Diligence Office are an important part of national security,
因此，‌"特勤局"的翻译在一定程度上准确地反映了其职能和地位
Therefore, the translation (of "Secret Service") as "特勤局" on a certain level accurately reflects its function and status.

Very informative. But one should not change the translation when the original still remains the same.
